# Alias "cd" so that it will automatically autocomplete and attempt to move to directory

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, alias, cd

I'm wondering if anyone can do this. Say I have this folder structure:

```
Folder A
    Folder Apple
    Folder Orange
```

If I am currently in Folder A, I'd like it so that if I type "cd Ap" and hit enter, it'll automatically put me in the "Apple" subfolder. Essentially, it would attempt to autocomplete and open the folder based off the partial input.

If I am currently in Folder A, and I type "cd ap" and hit enter (lowercase "a"), I would get an error because it couldn't autocomplete to an actual subfolder name. Is this possible? I'm working in Korn.

Comment: Seems like it would have many unintended consequences. What's wrong with hitting TAB to complete? Does Korn not support tab completion?

Comment: What do you want to do if there's also an "Apricot" directory?

Comment: @Cfreak good question; it's really just a small convenience thing. I can definitely do without, but it's just slower to have to hit ESC ESC or any other key every time I want to autocomplete a directory and enter it. It would basically function just like if I tried to autocomplete it manually and cd into it manually, except it's automated. I understand if this is more work than its worth. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite going to answer your question, but I'll get close. It seems to me like hitting the tab key isn't the hurdle for you, it's the capitalization. I know the feeling, it's like choosing between camelCase and inconvenient typing.

I've only done this in bash, my apoligies. If I recall, bash and ksh are rather close, so I'm hoping it will work for you.

`set completion-ignore-case on` turns on case-insensitive completion in bash.  Naturally this goes into any startup scripts you may want it in.

Good luck, tell us if it works in ksh !

Comment: Ah unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working, but thanks for the reply anyway! I might consider switching to bash; I hear it's better anyway. :P

Comment: @Carlin : Sorry to hear it doesn't work in ksh. It's one of the first things I do when settling into a system.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ksh function (untested)

```
cd () {
  typeset prefix=$1
  typeset destination=""
  for f in *; do
    [[ -d "$f" ]] || continue
    case "$f" in 
      "$prefix"*) destination="$f"; break ;;
    esac
  done
  if [[ -z "$destination" ]]; then
    print -u2 "error: can't find directory with prefix '$prefix'"
  else
    command cd "$destination"
  fi
}
```

With ksh, <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> is the equivalent of bash tab-completion.

Comment: Thanks glenn; unfortunately it gives me a "restricted: cd is a shell builtin" though. I appreciate the code!

Answer (score 0):

For Bash, you can add the following to your `~/.bashrc`.  By default, it will do case-insensitive matching.  It's a bit long, but it should handle anything you throw at it (except for trying to autocomplete `cd ../my_direc` from a symlink directory (see [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=531685#10) for more info on that).

If you use this script and leave it as case-insensitve, you might as well also add `bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'` to your `~/.bashrc` so that TAB-completion is also case-insensitive.

```
cd() {
    # Attempts to autocomplete the directory name
    #
    # If it fails to find a match, it'll still execute the input, in case the argument was
    # something like "-".
    case_insens=1 # set to one if you want it to try case-insensitive matching

    # for exact matches, cd immediately
    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        builtin cd "$1"
        return
    fi
    # deal with no arguments passed
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        builtin cd
        return
    fi

    # first loop for case-sensitive (since we prefer a case-sensitive match)
    # for more on this globbing, see: bit.ly/1CZ9qym
    for element in "$(dirname "$1")"/{*,.[!.]*,..?*}; do
        # skip if this result is not a directory
        [ -d "$element" ] || continue

        if [[ "$(basename "$element")" == "$(basename "$1")"* ]]; then
            # if there's no ambiguity, switch to that folder
            if [ $(find -L "$(dirname "$1")" -maxdepth 1 -name "$(basename "$1")*" -type d 2>/dev/null | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then
                echo "'$1' matches multiple results:  "
                echo "$(find -L "$(dirname "$1")" -maxdepth 1 -name "$(basename "$1")*" -type d 2>/dev/null)" 
                # try to cd anyway
                builtin cd "$1" &> /dev/null 
                unset case_insens element
                return
            else
                builtin cd "$element"
                unset case_insens element
                return              
            fi
        fi
    done

    if [ $case_insens -eq 1 ]; then
        #case-insensitive argument
        ci_arg="${1,,}"
    else
        builtin cd "$1"
        unset case_insens element
        return
    fi

    #Case-insensitive loop
    for element in "$(dirname "$1")"/{*,.[!.]*,..?*}; do
        # skip if this result is not a directory
        [ -d "$element" ] || continue   

        ci_element_name="$(basename "${element,,}")"
        if [[ "$ci_element_name" == "$(basename "$ci_arg")"* ]]; then
            # if there's no ambiguity, switch to that folder
            if [ $(find -L "$(dirname "$element")" -maxdepth 1 -iname "${ci_element_name}*" -type d 2>/dev/null | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then
                echo "'$ci_arg' matches multiple results:  "
                echo "$(find -L "$(dirname "$element")" -maxdepth 1 -iname "${ci_element_name}*" -type d 2>/dev/null)"
                # try to cd anyway
                builtin cd "$1" &> /dev/null
                unset ci_arg case_insens ci_element element
                return
            else
                builtin cd "$element"
                unset ci_arg case_insens ci_element element
                return
            fi
        fi
    done
    # we still haven't found a match, so pass the (faulty) argument to the cd command
    builtin cd "$1"
    unset ci_arg case_insens ci_element element
}
```

## Example Usage

```
cd ~
cd deskt
```

Comment: I know the OP asked about ksh, but I'm posting this for any Bash users who come across this question.